# How do I scale a motion capture animation?

Tags: animation, skeletal-animation, motion-capture

I used motion capture in my room using the Kinect. As I don't have much space I make compressed running moves, i.e. I put my legs up and down while not moving far forward.

How can I stretch the animation, so me walking 1 meters amounts to the skeleton walking 3 meters or similar while not exaggerating movements to the left/right?

Comment: This is extremely difficult because the style of your MoCap is wrong. So your entire animation is wrong. With MoCap data, you better get very good data directly (i.e. close to the final animation you need) because afterwards, editing MoCap data is not that easy.

Answer (score 1):

Run along a main axis (x, y, or z) and scale the animation along that axis.

If you don’t have a lot of space, you’re not going to produce a natural running gait. At best you’ll be able to use this as a basis for manual alterations, or a reference for a hand-done animation. One thing to try might be to undersell your movements along the axis of movement, so that they appear less distorted when scaled.

Alternatively, head to the gym with a laptop and set up your Kinect next to a treadmill.

Comment: "Run along a main axis (x, y, or z) and scale the animation along that axis.". This is not going to work. It will induce a lot of foot skating + the initial style of the animation is wrong so you will not be able to get it right afterwards.

Comment: @Korchkidu: Yeah, that’s why I qualified the hell out of it. :) A treadmill would be their best bet, I think.

Comment: Treadmills have armrests, also a huge display is in the way of the kinect - except you are running backwards, see http://www.treadmilltips.com/images/image-10-0-treadmill.jpg. Apart from that, this is really a good idea.